# Orion with RDBMS Data Base (No Mongo)

Tags: fiware-orion

is it possible to use a RDBMS Database, e.g PostgreSQL instead of MongoDB, for Orion Context Broker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. Orion uses MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

Orion uses MongoDB, however you can use Cygnus to persist your data into a PostgreSQL database.